# Drupal 7 Flags Module with Email Action Not Working?

Tags: email, drupal, drupal-7, action, flags

This is a very specific problem, but I'm experiencing an issue where I have 0 knowledge and experience.

I have the Flags Module 7.x-3.7 installed on Drupal 7.44. I was able to set up an 2 actions that send emails when a user activates a flag.

Now, all of a sudden I an unable to do so. The entire system hangs indefinitely whenever I: A) Click on the “edit” link for any flags the result in an email being sent or B) Try to create a new action using “Send e-mail” as the action.

I tried removing the modules, toggling other modules… the usual fare. I’m not massively familiar with Drupal, so the intereconnected workings have me a bit nervous to mess around. I am, however, familiar with PHP and MYSQL and have access to the root, so I can investigate pretty much wherever.

So,does anyone have any idea what could be causing this issue? Why does it not move past a connecting icon and move to the new page when the links are clicked? It’s not even a WSOD as far as I can tell.Any other information you need, please feel free to ask. I’m not even sure what’s needed to troubleshoot a Drupal 7 site, honestly, but any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the following line is causing an issue. It's in flag_actions.module, the function flag_actions_system_send_email_action_form(&$form, &$flag, $context):

$form['help']['basic'] = array(
    '#markup' => theme('flag_tokens_browser', array('types' => array('flag', 'flag-action'))),
  );

Commenting it out seems to solve the issue. I'd like to know WHY, and if it is safe to leave it commented out at the moment. Any ideas?